# Getting 1 testcase wrong using this method

Tags: python, combinations

There are three Hill Stations named A, B, and C. There are flights between each pair of Hill Stations. A one-way flight between the Hill Stations A and B (and vice versa) takes a hours, a one-way flight between Hill Stations B and C (and vice versa) takes b hours, a one-way flight between the Hill Stations C and A (and vice versa) takes c hours.

You are a tourist and you want to visit each of the hill stations exactly once. You can start at any of the stations. Find the minimum time taken to visit each Hill Station exactly once.

And this is the code I wrote:

```python
from itertools import combinations
ipl = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
l = combinations(ipl,2)
for i in l:
    print(i)
print(sum(min(l)))
```

Can someone help me with the reason which leads me to get one test case wrong?

Comment: what is the testcase you speak of?

Comment: I guess we're assuming the travel time between Home and any one hill station is the same? :)

Comment: @chepner i think you can start from any station and follow the times gives for travel between two stations

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the minimum path, and calculating its sum. But you want to get all the sums, and then get the minimum of those sums.

```
print(min(sum(path) for path in l))
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works because there are only 3 cities
You don't need combinations.

```
ipl = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(sorted(ipl)[:2])
```